# How come display none from javascript does not make thing disappear sometimes?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-7, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a stange situation I have come across simular things several times.  I think it might have something to do with having tons of tables and divs mixed together.  Sometimes, I use JavaScript to set a certain div, td, etc to display none, and some of it's content still shows on the screen.

I am sure I am using the correct JavaScript syntax.  I even step through the code and make sure the diaplay value it none.  This this case I also used developer tools to look at the dom.  In this case the element and all it's children are set to display:none.

I have seen this type of thing a few times.  Does anyont have any guess what is going on?

I am using ie8 in ie7 compat mode.

Grae

Comment: Do you have an example to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Have you validated your HTML?

Comment: IE7 has its problems, but disobeying "display: none" is not something I've ever seen.

Comment: This question cannot be answered in it's current form. You will need to supply an example of this behaviour.

Comment: Without an example, it's going to be very hard to *answer* this question. Randomly hypothesize about IE bugs, sure, but actually answering the question will require seeing the effect. I mean, `element.style.display = "none";` is pretty fundamental, hard to imagine IE getting it wrong.

Comment: @David Not really, it would take a long time to narrow down this problem in the code.  I was hoping someone would know what type of thing I should look for.

Comment: I don't know it helps, but the element seems to not be displayed, it is just it's scroll bar that is still there.

Comment: Maybe, I'll just have to come up with some testcase.

Comment: Its easy to guess without information-

'tons of tables and divs mixed together'- The divs can only be children of th or td elements,
or the entire table can be contained in a div, but anywhere else(around rows or table bodies) the browser has to decide where to put them. IE may be stacking empty divs before the table begins, and setting their display to none

Comment: I agree with you all I need more information.  I'll try to make a test case.

Comment: This question, as presented, is useless to others and should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the [!important declaration](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/importantdeclarations):

```
#foo { display: block !important; }
```

Or a very [specific selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/specificity):

```
#content div #foo { display: block; }
```

If either is used in the external CSS or inline style, it will override `display: none;`. Change the CSS or use `display: none !important;` in the JavaScript to workaround this.